# User can't login in lightdm only root can

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, window-manager, useradd, lightdm

I've installed arch, and lighDM with awesome window manager.
Everything runs okay.If I login as root, awesome load and works but if I login with the user I've created it attemps to log, clean te screen but reload the login screen,and here I'm in this login loop.

[This is my lightdm.log file](https://ibb.co/p4r8jN9) (Actually I can't export it cause the pc isn't working properly)

Thanks!

Comment: i googled `greeter requests session awesome` and found this ... https://askubuntu.com/questions/501702/lightdm-failed-to-start-session-user-folder-requesting-gnome#502365

Comment: @jsotola Thanks, I tried that but doesn't work :/

Comment: If the filesystem containing the user's home directory is 100% full, GUI login will fail because it needs to be able to write a few small files. Since root's home directory is not under `/home`, it may be on a different filesystem than the normal users... and some filesystem types may reserve a little bit of extra space for root's use only, just to prepare for problems like this.

Comment: @telcoM Sorry, i didn't understand you at all, should I move the directory's user? 
It's a fresh installation, it should have almost all free space

Comment: OK, then it's not likely to be a "filesystem full" problem, but something else. I don't know about Arch, but Debian makes a file named `~/.xsession-errors` to the user's home directory: if something that runs as that user causes the user session to fail, its error messages will be there. If Arch does something similar, those error messages might help in understanding the problem. The lightdm.log is the "system-wide view": it basically only says that the user session started and immediately ended, so something went wrong *within* the user's session.

Comment: Is it only lightdm that does this? Perhaps try installing a different display manager and see if it does the same (e.g. sddm)?

Comment: everything you need is only make a home directory for your user. check `/etc/passwd` to find where is home directory and `mkdir` it if not exist.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by reinstalling the whole SO, I didn't know if there's any other solution but nothing worked for me. Maybe if did sth wrong while creating the users or groups.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I created a user before installing xorg, lightdm and xfwm. So all I had to do was

```
$ userdel -r user_name # delete user
$ useradd -m user_name # add user again
$ passwd user_name # set a password
```

than logoff the root user and you should be able to logon as the user user_name.